# Including files from a directory

Tags: php

Does (a) have any benefits over (b)?

a) *A function that returns the path to the file.*

```
include util("array");

function util($name)
{
    return PATH."utils/$name.php";
}
```

b) *A function that directly includes the file.*

```
util("array");

function util($name)
{
    include PATH."utils/$name.php";
}
```

Comment: why not just `include PATH."utils/array.php";`?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, that would work but it would require more typing and it would make it very hard to rename the "utils" folder to lets say "helpers" some day.

Comment: Man, **you type it just once in a bootstrap file**. And then just copy-paste for the other projects. You are way overthinked it. Employ yourself with something real important. As for utils path, if there will be any sensible reason to rename, utilspath constant would be more appropriate.

Comment: nonsense, can't you just make a constant/variable that is same as `PATH.'utils/'` ?

Comment: @ajreal, sure but still `include UTIL_PATH."array.php` seems more redundant than `util("array")` and if you are willing to burden the namespace with another constant name why wouldn't you burden it with a function name instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using classes and `__autoload`

Answer (score 2):

I'd take the second option, because it would allow you to switch between `include()`, `include_once()`, `require()` and `require_once()` easily, in case you ever need that.

Comment: all this _once stuff is for lamers. try to write a program which can control it's flow